# highlight particular cells when the other dependent cell has a duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Conditional formatting to highlight cells when a particular number is shown more than once.

I have a set of core numbers that are fixed in the order numbers, but I want to highlight only those that have the core numbers shown more than once

Here are a few core numbers and how they are shown in the order numbers

Sample Order number

```
PMGAG5216GC
PMG005216GC
PMGVV5237GCB
PMG005237GCB
```

Core number that is common in that

```
5216
5327
```

I have added a new column that pulls out all the core numbers from the orders. Now I am doing a conditional format to identify the duplicates in the core numbers and based the duplicates highlighted I want to highlight the orders.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a helper column? If you extract these numbers anyways, why not right next to your order number? Then apply a conditional formula like `=COUNTIF(B:B,$B1)>1`

Comment: I am not sure if I am writing the formula wrong. Let me break it down. let's say I have the orders numbers in column A and the core numbers on column B and I have selected the A: A and did a conditional with this formula countif(B:B, B2) but there is no change in color

Answer (score 0):

I used a helper column to find the core number from each order number. The formula is shown below. Please note it is an array formula so you need to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to make it work then drag it down.

```
{=--MID(A2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),0),SUM(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1))))}
```

The next step is to set up conditional formatting with formula. **Highlight A2:A13**, and go to

Conditional Formatting -> New Rule... -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Then enter the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$13,$B2)>1
```

Please note the formula only works for the range as specified in my solution, you may need to redefine the range ($B$2:$B$13) if yours is different to mine.

See below screen-shot for more clarifications.
[image: Solution]